# Page can't load after add/removeclass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i got some problem when i was addclass and removeclass using jquery on my menu the problem is the page can't be load...

this my html :

```
<div class="menu-gila-container">
  <ul id="menu-gila" class="menu nav-menu">
    <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="home">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="html">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="css">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="php">PHP</a></li>
    <li><a href="mysql">MYSQL</a></li>
    <li><a href="gaze">GA TAU</a></li>
    <li><a href="gaze">GA TAU</a></li>
    <li><a href="diary">DIARE</a></li>
    <li><a href="ask">ASK ME</a></li>
    <li><a href="about">ABOUT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This my javascript :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.nav-menu li").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Remove the active class
        $("ul.nav-menu li").removeClass("current-menu-item");

        //Add the active tab to the selected tab
        $(this).addClass("current-menu-item"); 
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Please help me

Comment: why do you even set a "current" - class if you're going to do a pageload anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line `e.preventDefault();` it stops

OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul.nav-menu li").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("ul.nav-menu li").removeClass("current-menu-item"); //Remove the active class
        $(this).addClass("current-menu-item"); //Add the active tab to the selected tab
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')
    });
});
```

Add Active Navigation Class Based on URL

Example

HTML

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/clients/">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav-menu li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').prev().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: But if there is a redirection, what can be the purpose of adding/removing class on current page?

Comment: @A.Wolff i too have same question  in my mind .sure i will update ans

Comment: The purpose is a simple UX fail. Or maybe the intetion to see what links you already clicked ;)

Comment: url to be like this : www.example.com/undefined why ?

Comment: @YuliusArdianFebrianto You should really make some effort to explain what is the behaviour you are expecting, i still don't get it... And if your issue was just about redirection, quite strange you didn't have think by your own to test it by removing `e.preventDefault();` from your little piece of code

Comment: use href like this /html if you have page like  www.example.com/html

Comment: when i remove e.preventDefault(); the page load normally but class can't be add or remove

Comment: in your next page default you add class to that menu

Comment: @YuliusArdianFebrianto You have to use ajax then to load the content to current page... Make some effort next time, please...

Comment: @YuliusArdianFebrianto ok i will help you within a hr

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.nav-menu li").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('current-menu-item');
        $(this).addClass('current-menu-item');
    }); 
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/vY7cm/)

Comment: Thank's for your answer, add and remove class work normally but page still can't load